# Answers from another Stack Exchange Site

Tags: discussion

We've had a number of interesting questions on M&TV lately where the same essential question was asked and **extensively** answered on another SE site, specifically our sister site Science Fiction and Fantasy.

For a specific example:

This M&TV question: [What happened at the end of The Thing (1982)?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/104778/49)

Which has this SF&F answer: [Ending of John Carpenter's The Thing](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/93891/57069)

OR

M&TV: [Why was the DeLorean covered by ice?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104773/why-was-the-delorean-covered-by-ice)

SF&F: [Why was the DeLorean in Back To The Future not always covered in ice after time travel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/32128/why-was-the-delorean-in-back-to-the-future-not-always-covered-in-ice-after-time)

Summarising the SF&F answer seems redundant to me and I suppose I could copy the answer (as a Community Wiki) with **attribution** but that seems equally redundant.

**Then again**, even a **copied** answer on M&TV is a resource for *our* users going forward.

What are the community's thoughts... is there an ideal or preferred option here?

Comment: Since closing the question is entirely off the table, I'm not sure what else can be done. If you found an external internet source that answers the question, then using that source to answer it as we have always done seems like the way to go.

Comment: Sometimes sister site answer can give you the way to find even better answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that we should treat the sister site answer as though is was answered outside of the SE system.

The optimal solution, it seems to me, is to summarise the essential parts of the answer providing suitable quotes and linking the answer/question with suitable attribution to the original answerer.

*Apparently, making the M&TV answer a Community Wiki is not appropriate* so an upvote to the original answer (if you are a member of that site) is something that might be a suitable replacement rather than upvoting the attributed "copy".

Answer (score -1):

There should be a way in the system to cross-link questions between stacks. This way if it's fully discussed / answered in another stack we can just mark as "dupe in another stack" and have it linked.

Comment: Not going to happen, though. Also, the same question might get different answers, or answers from a different point of view, according to which stack it's on. So I don't even think this would be a good idea.